# Doubts related to the use of display: block CSS propery, my example don't work

Tags: html, css, layout, xhtml

I am finding some problem using **display: block**.

If you open this example link you can understand my problem: http://onofri.org/example/example3/

The HTML code is:

```
<div id="container">


    <div id="titleBox">
        <p id="myTitle">Promoting Investment in Agriculture</p>
    </div>

    <div id="columns">
        <div id="first">
            <p>BLA BLA BLA</p>
            <p>BLA BLA BLA</p>
            <p>BLA BLA BLA</p>
        </div>

        <div id="second">
            <p>BLA BLA BLA</p>
            <p>BLA BLA BLA</p>
            <p>BLA BLA BLA</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="reportBox">
        <p>REPORT</p>

        <div id="flagsContainer">

            <div id="reportEng"></div>
            <div id="reportFrn"></div>
            <div id="reportSpn"></div>
       </div>

</div>
</div>
```

And the CSS code is:

```
#titleBox{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 350px;
    background-color: #6da662;
    height: 40px;
    position:relative;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
}

#myTitle{
    /* consente di posizionare un elemento al centro del suo contenitore */
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16.5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 40px;
}

#columns{
    display: block;
}

#reportBox{
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 25px;
    width: 350px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: #EFEFEF;
    border: 1px solid #DFDFDF;
    font-family: Verdana;
    display: block;
}


#reportBox p{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #004673;
    padding-top: 5%;

}

#flagsContainer{
    width: 222px;
    height: 200px;
    min-height: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#reportEng{
    float: left;
    width: 64px;
    background-image: url(United-Kingdom2.png); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin-right: 10px;
    height: 60%;



    text-align: center;
}

#reportFrn{
    float: left;
    /*width: 133px;*/
    background-image: url(France2.png); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 64px;
    height: 60%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

#reportSpn{
    float: left;
    /*width: 133px;*/
    background-image: url(Spain2.png); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 60%;
    width: 64px;
    text-align: center;
}




#first{
    /*background-color: #8FBC8F;*/
    /* SFUMATURA BACKGROUND: */
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #35F2EC 0%, #16B7D6 50%, #016D94 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #35F2EC 0%, #16B7D6 50%, #016D94 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #35F2EC 0%, #16B7D6 50%, #016D94 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #35F2EC), color-stop(0.5, #16B7D6), color-stop(1, #016D94));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #35F2EC 0%, #16B7D6 50%, #016D94 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #35F2EC 0%, #16B7D6 50%, #016D94 100%);

    width: 200px;
    min-height: 300px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    float: left;
    /*margin-right: 15px;*/
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    box-shadow: 6px 7px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.37);
    -moz-box-shadow: 6px 7px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.37);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 6px 7px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.37);

}

#second{
    background-color: #8FBC8F;
    width: 200px;
    min-height: 300px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    float: right;
    /*margin-left: 15px;*/
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    box-shadow: 6px 7px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.37);
    -moz-box-shadow: 6px 7px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.37);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 6px 7px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.37);
}
```

As you can see, under the #titleBox div, I have a container div named **#columns** that contain two floated columns **#first** and **#second**

Now I want that the **#reportBox** div appears centered **UNDER** the **#columns** div and not (as is now) between the two columns.

Trying to optain this behavior I have try to set **display:block** on the **#columns** div and on the **#reportBox** div don't work.

Why? What have I to do to show the **#reportBox** under the **#columns** div?

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: Try adding `#reportBox { clear: both; }` or `#columns { min-height: 300px; }`

Answer (score 0):

try

```
clear: both
```

on #reportBox

reason being that floated elements float in relation to following elements. Putting clear: both on the element means that you want following element to appear after any of the floating elements. This really has nothing to do with the display: block;. div are display: block by default (unless of course you apply a float)

Answer (score 0):

I will explain more from the comment in this answer. The problem is `#columns` has no `height`, so when you `float` `#first` and `#second`, which are self contained `div`s, it leaves the space in the center for `#reportBox`.

The two options here are to either add:

```
#reportBox { 
    clear: both;
}
```

Which will, as it suggests, clears both the left and right floats.

or

```
#columns { 
    min-height: 300px; 
}
```

Which gives the container of `#first` and `#second` height, pushing `#reportBox` down as it's outside of the contiainer.

Hope this helps.